# Soldermask at home?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, solder-mask

I am interested in putting that nice green / red soldermask on the PCBs that I make at home.  The problem is I can't find a lot of information on it, like where to buy it, etc.  Do any hobbyists actually do this, or is it only for the pros?

CLARIFY:
I am interested in this technique not only to protect my board once it is complete, but also so I can give it a professional look.  I understand fully that I don't 'need' it for hobby type applications, but I am still interested in it.  Is this stuff that can actually be bought in reasonable quantities?  Is it very expensive, etc.  Does anybody know?

Answer (score 4):

Surely you can do soldermask, if you already mastered making PCBs using photomasks.
Material for soldermasks is also UV-sensetive, so you expose & develop it and that's it.

But unless you are using reflow soldering at home :-) , there is no much sence. 
You can solder even small-mid size BGA's without soldermask - just flux & practice.

Or if you badly want soldermask for BGA in small quantity - you can just take capton material, and manually make all required holes and then glue it to PCB.

Comment: Kapton tape is a good idea for this project. I think I'll try cutting some on my laser engraver to see how this works!  Do you know where you can get broader sheets of the stuff?

Comment: Unfortunately no :-|

Comment: You have a laser engraver?  Then, problem solved! Engravers will remove solder mask and leave the copper/tinplate untouched. Just spray-paint the board and laser away the paint on the pads.

Comment: @Mark - It sounds like you've done this before.  What sort of paint should be used?  It would have to be high-temperature and non-conductive, right?

Comment: Just regular enamel spray paint.  You should probably measure conductance yourself, just to be sure.

Comment: so where can one find this soldermask?

Answer (score 4):

As previously mentioned, conformal coating is a pretty good approach. We have some 10 year old PCBs here which are still in good condition. This is how we used to do it:

- Polish the PCB with Brasso until it looks beautifully shiny.
- Clean the PCB with methylated spirits.
- Buy some Liquid Latex.
- Use a small stick to apply a dot of latex to each pad that needs to be soldered.
- When the latex is dry, spray on the conformal coating.
- Lightly bake the boards until the coating is dry.
- Now peel off the latex dots.
- Clean the boards and you're good to go.

Comment: The best answer/information I could find since the past two days. Simple and clear. Tank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Soldermask is a special layer on PCBs that is meant to keep the solder onto the pads. This is only useful if you want to wave solder. I am not aware of a way to do that at home, because you need to have a mask to keep it off the pads. It is usually applied in a screen printing or photoimageable process. If you make your own PCBs, they will not be fine enough to profit from this.

If you want to add a shiny protective layer after soldering, you may want to try conformal coating. Perhaps something like http://www.electrolube.com/docs/conformalmain.asp?id=76

Comment: Soldermask is useful for several other reasons than making it easier to "machine solder" (I assume you mean wave): including but not limited to reducing corrosion, controlling impedance, and reducing bridging between fine pitch pads.

Comment: But those thing can be done with conformal coating as mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

[This process](http://retromaster.wordpress.com/pcb-making/) describes using pebeo vitrea (a stained glass paint) as a solder mask. I have not yet tried as I'm still working on perfecting my clothes iron technique, but the results that site shows are very promising.

Better yet, there's an [ebay store](http://cgi.ebay.com/Pebeo-Vitrea-160-Frosted-Colors-/250724454613?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&var=&hash=item800fa473d1#ht_500wt_922) that sells a whole bunch of different colors for a pretty cheap price.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for protection for the board, you could go with a spray-on coating. [This](http://www.tc-11.com/Marine%20Electronics%20Test.pdf) tests a few different ones for marine use. Since they are all designed for wet/salty conditions, they should protect the boards well under any normal conditions.